# Is Kaufhalle a regionalism?

Tags: regional

Is a *Supermarkt* the same as *Kaufhalle*? I met people in East Germany saying *Kaufhalle*.

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaufhalle

Comment: Thank you. But Wikipedia is wrong. The word is still very alive there.

Comment: The article does not contradict that. In fact, it doesn't say anything about the present. You could consider it incomplete, but not wrong.

Comment: They write "wurden ... bezeichnet"

Comment: Actually, they write "wurden in der DDR ... bezeichnet".

Comment: The wiki page to [Supermarkt](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermarkt) indicates that it's still in present use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Supermarkt* is the more polished, West German word. *Kaufhalle* is a more descriptive, hence more East German variant.

Comment: Der Halle hört man Wände und Decke an, während der Markt mehr nach Pferdemist und Schlamm klingt. Allerdings kaschiert die westliche Version, dass man womöglich Geld los wird.

Comment: I disagree with the juxtaposition of polished/more descriptive. All my Berlin friends who grew up in the GDR, now in their thirties/forties, still use "Kaufhalle" on a regular basis (sometimes ironic, though).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "Kaufhalle" is indeed a word that says  "DDR" at least as strongly as "Zweiraumwohnung".

Answer (score 1):

There was a supermarket chain called Kaufhalle, so if someone said he goes to Kaufhalle, he really goes to a shop named Kaufhalle. Last shop was closed in 2007 or 2005.
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaufhalle

Comment: You mean a different Wikipedia link: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaufhalle_AG – However, the range of goods was very different from a GDR _Kaufhalle_ or a FRG _Supermarkt_, and its importance was not such that it would become a generic term.